# Calling a WooCommerce instance from a class in a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is quite a simple question. I have a custom plugin  and a class Configurator. I am trying to programatically add a woocommerce product but I always get the `Call to a member function add_to_cart() on null` error. Even if I try some other method on the `WC()` instance which is an alternative to globally declaring `$woocommerce` I still get the same error. WooCommerce is installed and activated, version 3.0.7.

```
class Configurator {

    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_configurator_form_submit', array( $this, 'configurator_to_cart' )  );
        add_action( 'admin_post_configurator_form_submit', array( $this, 'configurator_to_cart' )  );

    }


    public function configurator_to_cart() {
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

         WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 25044, 1 );

        //wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=configurator'));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, WooCommerce Cart is a non object on admin-post, so the post has to be processed via admin-ajax.